# Left join in Neo4j does not seem to work

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is my graph
[image]

I am trying to make a query that tells me if the connections from a node of type `T` exist to nodes of type `M`. I heard that `OPTIONAL MATCH` is equivalent to SQL Left Join, but it does not include the the missing link.

Here is my attempt:

```
START t=node(241)
OPTIONAL MATCH t-[r:R]->(m)
RETURN m.name, r is not  NULL
```

and the result only has nodes `M1`, `M2`, `M3`.
[image]

I also want to include the row `M4 | false` in the result.

If I modify the query a bit

```
START t=node(241), m=node(246,247, 248, 249)
OPTIONAL MATCH t-[r:R]->(m)
RETURN m.name, r is not  NULL
```

then I can get the desirable result, but it requires me to know the ids of all the M nodes in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I felt kinda dump because I found the answer right after posting this.

All I need is an extra match to get all M nodes.

```
START t=node(241)
MATCH (m:M)
OPTIONAL MATCH t-[r:R]->(m)
RETURN m.name, r is not  NULL
```